# BizTalk WCF-Custom sqlbinding not sending parameters to stored procedure

Tags: biztalk

I am redeploying an old Biztalk 2010 project to a new Biztalk 2016 server. The code hasn't changed at all - as far as I can tell - so it should just be a straight deployment. I am very much a BizTalk newbie but I have managed to get it all set up. However, when I send a message it works through the orchestration until it gets to the point where it should call a stored proc - which it does - but it doesn't send the parameters. There is an audit step beforehand so I can see that it has generated the message with the values and the schema for the stored proc is there but I can't see why it isn't sending the values. Anyone have any idea why?

I have checked every setting against a live-running version and it all seems to be the same. I'm tearing my hair out and I have precious little to spare.

Comment: How exactly do you know it's not sending the parameter values?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, well I did an SQL trace and the store proc is using default input values so I'm assuming that the values are not being passed

Comment: So why not re-generate the schema for the stored procedure?  This will also give you the correct bindings so you can re-create the port.

Comment: I was really hoping not to have to do that. It’s a really big project with around 40 schemes. Oh well :-(

Comment: Maybe try with one of them and compare it to the original.  Then you maybe able to work out the difference and apply it to the rest.